# Is there a way to do this with basic JS DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to apply/remove to an input field according to a user's selection in a separate drop down form - but I can't figure out how to target the input's class.

I need to add/remove the 'pageRequired' class from this input:

```
<input  type="text" title="Company Required" name="customfields-tf-2-tf" class="inputclass pageRequired textInput" id="customfields-tf-2-tf" />
```

When the user selects one of two options from a drop down field. For example:

```
<select class="dropdown" name="customfields-s-1-s" id="customfields-s-1-s" >
<option value="Owner"<?php if(in_array("Owner",$temp_values)) { ?> selected='selected'<?php } ?>> Owner</option>
<option value="Broker"<?php if(in_array("Broker",$temp_values)) { ?> selected='selected'<?php } ?>> Broker</option>
</select>
```

If the user selects broker than I want to add the pageRequired class to the first input field and remove it if the user selects Owner.

EDIT- Ok, so here is the code I am working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeClass(myDropdown) {
   if (#customfields-s-1-s.selectedIndex == 1 ) {
       $('#customfields-tf-2-tf').addClass('pageRequired');
   }
   else {
      $('#customfields-tf-2-tf').removeClass('pageRequired');
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done very simply using jquery:

Just add the onchange event to your dropdown and then call a function that either removes the class or adds it depending on the dropdown selection

```
<select class="dropdown" name="customfields-s-1-s" id="customfields-s-1-s" onchange="javascript:changeClass(this);" >

function changeClass(myDropdown) {
   if (myDropdown.selectedIndex == 1 ) {
       $('#customfields-tf-2-tf').addClass('pageRequired');
   }
   else {
      $('#customfields-tf-2-tf').removeClass('pageRequired');
   }
}
```

Here are the links on use:

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: So with jquery I can just add classes like that? I have multiple classes applied, is that going to effect it?

Comment: it should be fine with multiple classes.  Look at the links on use there is an example with multiple class add and remove.

Comment: There's also a `.toggleClass()` that makes this even shorter: `$('#customfields-tf-2-tf').toggleClass('pageRequired', myDropdown.selectedIndex == 1);`

Comment: I can't quite get this to work, have I targeted the dropdown correctly?
I added the code I am using to the OP.

Comment: Did you add the onchange to the dropdown?

Comment: Yeah, I added this to the dropdown: 
`onchange="changeClass"`

Comment: Wait I got it - added this:
`onchange="javascript:changeClass(this);"`

That was dumb, sorry...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use JQuery you can also do this with just plain JavaScript:

```
<script>
function changeClass(obj) {
  var input = document.getElementById("customfields-tf-2-tf");
  if(obj.value == 'Broker') {
    input.className = input.className.replace('pageRequired','');
  }
  else if(obj.value == 'Owner') {
    input.className = input.className + ' pageRequired';
  }
}
</script>

<input title="Company Required" id="customfields-tf-2-tf" class="inputclass pageRequired textInput" type="text">
<br>
<select name="matt" onchange="changeClass(this)">
<option value="Owner">Owner</option>
<option value="Broker">Broker</option>
</select>
```